# Outbound Internet Connectivity for ECS Fargate instances with AssignPublicIp set to DISABLED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a container running as a Service on AWS ECS Fargate. It is running in a Public subnet. The Service's associated Security Group allows for Egress on all ports and IPs. i.e. outbound rules are unrestricted. For its AwsvpcConfiguration, I intentionally have `AssignPublicIp:` set to `DISABLED`. I have no issues with internet connectivity when it's set to `ENABLED`, but I don't want that in order to comply with my organization's security requirements. I am concerned about having a public IP exposed to the internet; I'd rather have all inbound traffic only flow through my ALB.

What am I missing here in order to get my container to make an outbound call to the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place your ECS tasks/service in a [private](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html) subnet with routes to a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html). NAT gateway should be in a public subnet.